# Как уменьшить объём используемой памяти в проге?

Tags: python, python-3.x, память

Есть вот такой код:

```
a = int(input())
spis = [1]
while len(spis) < a:
    b = a - len(spis)
    prom = spis[:b]
    for i in prom:
        spis.append(i*2)
        if len(spis) >= a:
            break
    prom = []
print(max(spis[:a]))
```

Он ищет максимальное число в списке длиной `a`, но не проходит тесты по объёму памяти, как уменьшить объём используемой памяти?

Comment: масимальное число ищет только последняя строчка. Что делают все остальные?

Comment: Остальные формируют список, в котором и должно искаться число. Формируются так: берутся все числа основого списка и умножаются на 2, затем добавляются в этот же список, и так до тех пор, пока длина списка не станет равна `a`

Comment: Вот именно там и проблема, а не "ищет максимальное число".

Comment: @DGDays А в условиях задачи говорится что надо хранить в памяти весь список ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

эту задачу можно решить так:

```
print(2**(len(bin(a))-3))
```

Answer (score 6):

При этом алгоритме список можно даже не формировать, а максимум не искать. Его можно вычислить: он равен `2**int(math.log2(a))`.